# how to loop through each cells and rows in datagridview and negate the values (1 to -1, 10 to 10, etc.)

Tags: c#, .net

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in productData.Rows)
{
    if (productData.Columns["availablequantity"].Index < 0)
    {
        row.Cells[productData.Columns["availablequantity"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[productData.Columns["availablequantity"].Index].Value) * -1);
    }
    //end of if
    else if (productData.Columns["availablequantity"].Index > 0)
    {
        row.Cells[productData.Columns["availablequantity"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[productData.Columns["availablequantity"].Index].Value) * 1);
    }
    //end of else if
}
```

Thanks for help and fast answer !

PS:I thing I'm just over thing it it seams just to be a stupid little error ...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: i m not get proper output suppose i have value of - then it should convert + right. It is not giving me that output

Comment: Your edit has confused me now. Based on your original title (which I tried to clear up) it seemed to be that you wanted to convert -1 to 1 and 1 to -1, etc. but not it seems that you want the absolute value (negative values become positive, positive values are unchanged). Also your code seems to be checking the index (position) of the column for its value relative to 0, not the cell value.

Comment: yes sorry for that.

Comment: this is rude of me can you provide me the solution with code

Comment: You should check the value of cell in if condition. For example `if(row.Cells[productData.Columns["availablequantity"].Index].Value<0)`

Comment: You can use column name instead of index. `if(row.Cells["availablequantity"].Value<0)`

Comment: this didn't work Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the values in all the columns, or just in one ("availablequantity")?

Comment: only one column.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through every row and cell, you can use foreach loop. Is this what you need?

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.Rows)
{
  foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
  {
    //do operations with cell
  }
}
```

Comment: *it is giving me the*  Error 31 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' does not contain a definition for 'cell' and no extension method 'cell' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: row.cell["availablequantity"].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.cell["availablequantity"].Value) * -1); 'this way right.'

Comment: because I m new to asp .net programming

Comment: DataGridView  is in windows forms, In ASP.Net it is GridView. What kind of application you are building.

Comment: product inventory

Answer (score 0):

You are making this far too difficult.  Get the index once and store it in a variable, then just use the variable.  If you are reversing the sign, all you need to do is multiply by -1 so the code becomes:

```
int idx = productData.Columns["availablequantity"].Index;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in productData.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[idx].Value = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[idx].Value) * -1;
}
```

Comment: You attempted to edit my answer with a screenshot of the output.  That output would not be generated by my code, so you are obviously doing something different.  Unfortunately we do not have a crystal ball; we cannot help you, if we cannot see what you are doing wrong.  Please edit your question, with the code you are using now, show us the inputs, the results and how the results should be.